# Having trouble updating winnings in blackjack game

Tags: python, blackjack

Self teaching Python. This is a simple blackjack game I've been working on through a online instruction video. The game runs well enough, but I cant seem to update my winnings or losses back into the pot after a game. I have a feeling it could have something to do with the clear_output() I use after the take bets function. What am I doing wrong?
Firstly, my chips class is here.

```
class Chips:
    def __init__(self):
        self.total = 100
        self.bet = 0
    def win_bet(self):
        self.total += self.bet
    def lose_bet(self):
        self.total -= self.bet
```

Then I go into defining functions

```
def player_busts(player,dealer,chips):
    print("You busted. Too bad.")
    chips.lose_bet()

def player_wins(player,dealer,chips):
    print("You win!")
    chips.win_bet()

def dealer_busts(player,dealer,chips):
    print("Dealer busts!")
    chips.win_bet()

def dealer_wins(player,dealer,chips):
    print("Dealer wins!")
    chips.lose_bet()

def take_bet(chips):
    clear_output()
    print('Welcome to Adams BlackJack!')
    print('Get as close to 21 as you can without going over!')
    print('You have '+str(chips.total)+' chips.')

    while True:
        try:
            chips.bet = int(input('How much would you like to bet, hotshot? '))
        except ValueError:
            print('Sorry, your bet must be an integer!')
        else:
            if chips.bet > chips.total:
                print("Sorry, you don't have that much money.",chips.total)
            else:
                break
```

Then I go into the actual code that runs the game.

```
playing = True
while True:

    deck = Deck()
    deck.shuffle()


    player_hand = Hand()
    player_hand.add_card(deck.deal())
    player_hand.add_card(deck.deal())

    dealer_hand = Hand()
    dealer_hand.add_card(deck.deal())
    dealer_hand.add_card(deck.deal())

    player_chips = Chips()
    print("\nYour chips: ",player_chips.total)

    take_bet(player_chips)
    show_some(player_hand,dealer_hand)

    while playing:
        hit_or_stand(deck,player_hand)
        show_some(player_hand,dealer_hand)

        if player_hand.value > 21:
            player_busts(player_hand,dealer_hand,player_chips)
            break
    if player_hand.value <= 21:
        while dealer_hand.value < 17:
            hit(deck,dealer_hand)

        show_all(player_hand,dealer_hand)

        if dealer_hand.value > 21:
            dealer_busts(player_hand,dealer_hand,player_chips)

        elif dealer_hand.value > player_hand.value:
            dealer_wins(player_hand,dealer_hand,player_chips)

        elif dealer_hand.value < player_hand.value:
            player_wins(player_hand,dealer_hand,player_chips)

        else:
            push(player_hand,dealer_hand)

    print("\nYour chips: ",player_chips.total)

    new_game = input("Would you like to play another hand? Enter 'y' or 'n' ")

    if new_game[0].lower()=='y':

        playing=True
        continue
    else:
        print("Thanks for playing! bye now, mmkay?")
        break
```

Is it possible to add a line in my if statement that adds my winnings to my total chips?

Comment: Did you ever set `self.bet` to the appropriate values? Perhaps you need to show some more code. Your error cannot be determined solely from the information provided so far

Comment: @sshashank124 Sorry about that. I just added a snip to this.

Comment: I think you may want to edit your question again and show more code - it's hard to tell what's going on without seeing more. One thing that stands out to me though is that in your `take_bets` functions you have two separate `Chips` instances, one called `chips` (the parameter of the function) and `player_chips` (presumably a global object, which lives outside of the scope of this function). From the way your code is written, you are treating these two objects like they are the same. Are they? It seems to me you should use one or the other, but not both.

Comment: @user10987432 thank you for the reply. I've added everything pertaining to chips and betting.

Comment: I'd suggest improving the title so it's easier for people to find it

Comment: @Adam I believe the simple fix would be to simply move `player_chips = Chips()` outside of the outer for-loop, on the same level of indentation as `playing = True`. The way the code is written now, every time you start a new game, you are instantiating a new `Chips` object and assigning it to `player_chips`, effectively resetting your total chip count (if I've understood the problem correctly.)

Comment: @user10987432 So I moved the Player_chips = Chips(), as you stated and the system works flawlessly now. THANK YOU!